# How would I explain why a top wobbles to someone who has never taken a physics course?

Tags: rotation, precession

I found this [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/top.html/%22this%22) website that explains the precession of a top, but obviously, it is not comprehensible to a younger student. I am not referring to why tops stay up, just why they make circles that increase in size and then fall over. The person that I am explaining it to does at least understand gravity and Newton's laws.

Comment: I find [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession#Classical_.28Newtonian.29) and the image beside it show a fairly clear picture.

Comment: How would you explain it to someone who *has* taken a physics course?

Comment: This video is absolutely amazing: https://youtu.be/XHGKIzCcVa0 (Spinning, by Vsauce) (added as a comment because my answer apparently violated policy...)

Comment: @HritikNarayan Thank you! That video is great and I would accept this if it was an answer.